# Can I quickly shift audio and video tracks on a video file?

Tags: sound, video, audio-sync

I have a handful of videos where the audio track is a few seconds off. So the lips move and then the words come out. I am hoping there’s a way (maybe even on the command line, as my computer is really not set up with the RAM for video editing) to shift the audio track back or forward by milliseconds.

Is there a command line tool I can use to shift the timing of an audio track in an MP4

Comment: I haven't messed with one yet, but it is possible with ffmpeg:  https://superuser.com/questions/982342/in-ffmpeg-how-to-delay-only-the-audio-of-a-mp4-video-without-converting-the-au

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tool is probably `ffmpeg` as described at
[In ffmpeg, how to delay only the audio of a .mp4 video without converting the audio?](https://superuser.com/questions/982342/in-ffmpeg-how-to-delay-only-the-audio-of-a-mp4-video-without-converting-the-au)

(Though the solution there actually just stripped the audio and subtitles completely, so I still have some research to do.)